# How to change URL of my pages?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, site-url

At the moment my pages are:

```
domain.com/page
```

And I want to look them like:

```
domain.com/example/page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined [this nice solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30723/2807) for adding an additional option to the permalinks page and [this snippet](http://wpforce.com/change-wordpress-page-permalinks/) for adding a custom base name to page permalinks.

### Usage

Save the snippet below as `wpse238124-page-base.php`, place it in your plugins directory, and activate *Page Base* on your plugins page. Then, visit your permalinks page, enter your desired page base name e.g. `example`, and save the changes.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Page Base
Plugin URI:
Description: Enables adding a base to page permalinks.
Version: 0.0.1
Author:
Author URI:
License: GPL2/Creative Commons
*/

function wpse238124_page_base_load_permalinks() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wpse238124_page_base'] ) ) {
        update_option( 'wpse238124_page_base', sanitize_title_with_dashes( $_POST['wpse238124_page_base'] ) );
    }

    // Add a settings field to the permalink page
    add_settings_field( 'wpse238124_page_base', __( 'Page Base' ), 'wpse238124_page_base_field_callback', 'permalink', 'optional' );
}
add_action( 'load-options-permalink.php', 'wpse238124_page_base_load_permalinks' );

function wpse238124_page_base_field_callback() {
    $value = get_option( 'wpse238124_page_base' );  
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" name="wpse238124_page_base" id="wpse238124_page_base" class="regular-text" />';
}

function wpse238124_page_base_rules() {
    $page_base = get_option( 'wpse238124_page_base' );

    if ( ! $page_base ) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . $page_base . '/%pagename%/'; 
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse238124_page_base_rules' );
```