# Custom post type translation

Tags: custom-post-types, translation, textdomain

I would like to translate the name of a custom post type with page capabilities. I'm using qtranslate-x but even it works for custom posts, it doesn't translate the custom post type name. I.e. my custom post type in Italian is: **Elettroevoluti** but when I try to recall it from url through qtranslate-x in English it is still /en/elettroevoluti and not /en/electroevolved (translated).

How can I get rid of it?

Here my code:

```
function elettroevoluti_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Elettroevoluti', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Elettroevoluto', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Elettroevoluti', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Elettroevoluti', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Elettroevoluto', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array('editor', 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'elettroevoluti', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'elettroevoluti_type', 0 );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Theme localization of "slugs" (custom post types, taxonomies)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/theme-localization-of-slugs-custom-post-types-taxonomies)

Comment: Hello and thank you. It didn't worked for me unfortunately...